# Javascript const declaration with braces

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax-error, electron

Electron's documentation (for example http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/) says to import some features using a destructuring statement:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
```

This works when running the code in Electron but Jasmine and Visual Studio* claim that the "{" is a syntax error.

What is the correct usage?

*The code is actually written in Typescript (1.8 targeting ES2015) but the transpiled code in JS is identical in this case.

Comment: It's called Destructuring Assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is valid ES6/ES2015, but is not valid ES5.

Destructuring assignments [are supported in node.js >= 6.4](http://node.green/#destructuring--declarations). If your Jasmine is run with an older version, it will not work. Not sure about Visual Studio, but it looks like you need a recent version of VS 2015 to be able to have ES6 features.

Therefore you should either update your tools, or just configure Typescript so it targets ES5 instead.